# Is "let go your hand" grammatically correct?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

Wherever "let go of your hand" is used, can "let go your hand" be used in its place? Is there any difference at all?

Comment: It sounds strange to say out loud, something that would be said in an old play

Answer (score 5):

"Let go your hand" is grammatically correct, but archaic. See Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar:* "let slip the dogs of war."

Comment: This has the most upvotes but it  doesn't follow. The question is about 'of'.  It would be incorrect to say say, "Let slip **of** the dogs of war" so the quotation does not provide a justification: either that the original phrase is archaic or that it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't drop the prepostion *of* in the expression *let go of*.

The expression *let go* is used for ceasing employment, so the result could easily become confusing or misleading.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is incorrect, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to comment and got distracted. First, I think the context would rule out any confusion over what was being _let go_ and in what sense. Second, your answer doesn't address whether or not this use is grammatically correct, which seems to be the reason for the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing grammatically incorrect in your phrase.

Consider thus:

```
    Let your hand go.
```

It is the same, where "your hand" is the direct object of the verb "let".
You've simply inverted part of the sentence, which has no bearing on the grammatical soundness thereof.

It *does* sound a bit odd, all the same, at least, to me (native US English speaker) it does.

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish we say "letting go of hands" or literally "soltarse de las manos". I think in English it would be like "hands off" or "release your hands" but I don't know if it replaces "let go your hand".

Answer (score 0):

As other stated - grammatically correct, but bit odd and even ambiguous, unclear.

Therefore the meaning is not the same:

> Let your hand go

(tonybaldwin's example)

is different from

> Let go of your hand

(which does imply it was held, where the first example does not)

Comment: How can you let something go, if you are not holding it?

Comment: You can let go in a sense of: to relax, to let it be spontaneous and also to give up on something or to release from employment. There is overlap in most senses, but I still feel that with 'let go of your hand' there is a stronger implication of actually holding something with that same hand.

Comment: Can I have an explanation of the downvote, it is hard to improve with no feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If it were "Let go my hand", I would have no hesitation in accepting it as a spoken alternative to "Let go of my hand".

But "Let go your hand" is odd, because "Let go of your hand" is an unlikely thing to say, so I would probably interpret it as "Let go (of something) with your hand".

Answer (score 0):

In context of the whole it is perfectly understandable, and therefore correct and acceptable English; writing gospel song lyrics and poetry I find it is literary and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

In modern, informal (usually rapid) speech, a constituent can be placed at  the end of a sentence for focus. The constituent can be one that's not actually licensed by the argument structure of the clause.

In the OP's example (archaic reading aside), *your hand* is not actually licensed. The phrasal verb *let go* takes a subject, and possibly a *for-* prepositional phrase as a complement. It does not take a direct object. But you add *your hand* for assertive focus. This construction is grammatical, but only in informal speech (including a written account of a conversation), not in formal writing.

Another example: *Turn it down that noise.* Here *that noise* is normally not licensed because *it* already fills the object position, but it gets tacked on to the end of the utterance for focus.